# How to show Git branches grouped by name?

Tags: git

When looking at a listing of all the branches I'm often trying to figure out whether

1. there are any local branches I haven't yet pushed (that is, they appear locally but not on the remote),
2. there are any local branches which have been deleted from the remote (also appear locally but not on the remote), or
3. there's a new remote branch I should check out.

In all cases I would want local branch `X` and remote branch `X` to appear next to each other, but branches are instead listed local-first and then per remote:

```
$ git branch --all
  feat/foo
* main
  oof
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/feat/foo
  remotes/origin/release-0.1
  remotes/upstream/HEAD -> upstream/main
  remotes/upstream/release-0.1
```

Is there some built-in functionality which groups branches by name, like below?

```
$ git branch --all --group-by-name
  feat/foo
  remotes/origin/feat/foo
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/upstream/HEAD -> upstream/main
  oof
  remotes/origin/release-0.1
  remotes/upstream/release-0.1
```

Comment: No, there's no built-in functionality to do this. Write your own code to sort them as you see fit, and then set that up as a git alias.

Comment: `git branch -vv` will display the local branches alongside their upstream references if any. Like @larsks said, I don't think there is any option to sort the way you want.